# Combine two rdds

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to spark ,Could someone help me find a way to combine two rdds to create a final rdd as per the below logic in scala preferably without using sqlcontext(dataframes) -

RDD1=column1,column2,column3  having 362825 records

RDD2=column2_distinct(same as from RDD1 but containing distinct values),column4  having 2621 records

Final RDD=column1,column2,column3,column4

Example-

RDD1 =

```
  userid |  progid  |  Rating
       a       001     5
       b       001     3
       b       002     4
       c       003     2
```

RDD2=

```
   progid(distinct) |   id

   001                  1
   002                  2
   003                  3
```

Final RDD=

```
    userid  | progid  | id | rating
        a       001      1   5
        b       001      1   3
        b       002      2   4
        c       003      3   2
```

code

```
val rawRdd1 = pairrdd1.map(x => x._1.split(",")(0) + "," + x._1.split(",")(1) + "," + x._2) //362825 records    

val rawRdd2 = pairrdd2.map(x => x._1 + "," + x._2) //2621 records    

val schemaString1 = "userid programid rating"    

val schemaString2 = "programid id"    

val fields1 = schemaString1.split(" ").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, nullable = true))    

val fields2 = schemaString2.split(" ").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, nullable = true))    

val schema1 = StructType(fields1)    
val schema2 = StructType(fields2)    


val rowRDD1 = rawRdd1.map(_.split(",")).map(attributes => Row(attributes(0), attributes(1), attributes(2)))    

val rowRDD2 = rawRdd2.map(_.split(",")).map(attributes => Row(attributes(0), attributes(1)))    

val DF1 = sparkSession.createDataFrame(rowRDD1, schema1)    

val DF2 = sparkSession.createDataFrame(rowRDD2, schema2)    


DF1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")    

DF2.createOrReplaceTempView("df2")    


val resultDf = DF1.join(DF2, Seq("programid"))    

val DF3 = sparkSession.sql("""SELECT df1.userid, df1.programid, df2.id, df1.rating FROM  df1 JOIN df2 on df1.programid == df2.programid""")    


println(DF1.count())  //362825 records    

println(DF2.count())  //2621 records    

println(DF3.count())  //only 297 records
```

expecting same number of records as DF1 with a new column attached from DF2 (id) having corresponding value of programid from DF2`

Comment: you can achieve this with a simple join.

Comment: Tried doing that, but join is not giving me the correct number of records

Comment: Add some code to the question so we can check the logic.

Comment: Its more good if you are going to use datasets or dataframe

Comment: @jamborta: Added the sql logic to the question

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit ugly but should work (Spark 2.0):

```
 val rdd1 = sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(List("a,001,5", "b,001,3", "b,002,4","c,003,2"))
 val rdd2 = sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(List("001,1", "002,2", "003,3"))

 val groupedRDD1 = rdd1.map(x => (x.split(",")(1),x))
 val groupedRDD2 = rdd2.map(x => (x.split(",")(0),x))
 val joinRDD = groupedRDD1.join(groupedRDD2)
 // convert back to String
 val cleanJoinRDD = joinRDD.map(x => x._1 + "," + x._2._1.replace(x._1 + ",","") + "," + x._2._2.replace(x._1 + ",",""))
 cleanJoinRDD.collect().foreach(println)
```

I think better option is to use spark SQL

Comment: Thanks, I had tried this but did not get the correct number of records in final rdd-
    
`val groupedRDD1 = rdd1.map(x => (x.split(",")(1),x))  // 362825  records`

` val groupedRDD2 = rdd2.map(x => (x.split(",")(0),x)) // 2621  records (since contains only unique values for the key column ) `

`val cleanJoinRDD = joinRDD.map(x => x._1 + "," + x._2._1.replace(x._1 + ",","") + "," + x._2._2.replace(x._1 + ",",""))  //297 records `

whereas i was expecting the cleanJoinRdd to have same number of records as rdd1 i.e.362825 with the corresponding values (from keys of rdd2 )as new column.

Comment: why u can't use dataframes/datasets?

Comment: Tried using that.. have updated the question with the code .Still not getting the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you split, concatenate and split the row again? You could just do it in one step:

```
val rowRdd1 = pairrdd1.map{x => 
    val (userid, progid) = x._1.split(",") 
    val rating = x._2
    Row(userid, progid, rating) 
}
```

My guess that your problem might be that there are some additional characters in your keys so the don't match in the joins. A simple approach would be to do a `left join` and inspect the rows where they don't match.

It could be something like extra space in the rows which you could fix like this for both rdds:

```
val rowRdd1 = pairrdd1.map{x =>  
    val (userid, progid) = x._1.split(",").map(_.trim)
    val rating = x._2
    Row(userid, progid, rating) 
}
```

Comment: My ultimate aim is to feed the final rdd into the `org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating`  method , but since the method accepts only integers as products and i have values as long as 17 digits which is why i have to map it to something like 'id' column (downcasting), Let me know if you feel there is a better way to feed Long types in Rating method for ALS.

Comment: @Amit my main point here was about the extra character in the keys that you use for joins. Go ahead and ask a separate question on how to feed the `Rating` method.